# N-N table and WPF databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have 3 data tables:

### User

`UserID`, `UserName`
1, Bat
2, John
etc...

### Member

`MemberID`, `Member`
1, Local
2, Zone
etc...

### UserMember

`UserID`,`MemberID`
1, 1
1, 2
2, 1
etc...

**On the user input XAML Form in WPF**
Check list box is bound to the `Member` table.

## My Question:

I want it so that when the user checks the member type, the selected values automatically gets inserted into the `UserMember` table. And when the the user unchecks member type, the selected values are deleted from the `UserMember` table.

How can I do this in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of software methodology you want to use (I like MVVM with WPF) what kind of ORM(Linq, EF, Castle, etc.).

your could create a ViewModel like so:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
  int UserId {get;set;}
  Collection<Member> MemberList {get;set;}
}

public class Member
{
  bool _IsMember;
  bool IsMember 
  {get return _IsMember;set _IsMember = value; EditMemberStatus();}
  int MemberId {get;set;}
  string Member {get;set;}

  void EditMemberStatus()
  {
    if (IsMember)
      //Code to add row into db using your ORM choice
    else
      //Code to remove row from db
  }
}
```

in your xaml you could do this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding MemberList}>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="IsMember"}>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsMember}"/>
      </GridViewColumn
      <GridViewColumn Header=Member DisplayMemberBinding={Binding Member}/>
    </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And finally in the code behind of your xaml you have this

```
public class UserView
{
  UserView()
  {
     InitializeComponent(); 
     DataContext= new UserViewModel();
  }
}
```

This is just a skeleton, hope this helps. It's also only one way of a myriad of ways to do it.